# BigQuery: How to share job results?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

User A runs a job.
User A shares link to the Job with User B.

User B can see the Job details, but not the results:

```
User does not have permission to access results of another user's job
```

Two questions:

1. Why?
2. Is there a way to allow user B to see the results without persisting them into a permanent table?

Comment: If there is a permission error, what are the permissions of the user B?

Comment: User B is "project owner"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good questions!! Why? I don't know. I got strange result when I tried [to `getIamPolicy` on the temporary table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/getIamPolicy). I got a error 500 "Unknown"

I suppose that cached table is only accessible by the user that created it. It should be a legacy mode.

---

A solution to solve your issue is to impersonate the same service account by the User A when it perform the request and by the user B when it read the request.

Like that, the same user, the service account, create the query and read it, even if the originators aren't the same.

---

**EDIT1**

If impersonation is not a solution, you can persist temporary the data in a BigQuery table. Define a dataset for that temporary table, and set a [table expiration parameter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#create-dataset).

The minimal duration is 1h, but you can handle it as a normal table and it will be cleaned automatically. It's pretty similar than BigQuery cached query, but this time, it's sharable!

Comment: Thanks Guillaume! Unfortunately, impersonation is not a good security practice and introduces more issues than it solves.

Comment: I proposed something else. Nothing magic, but another point of view!